# How to stop the height growth of the div?

Tags: html, css

why when I try to embed a tiktok on my page, does the height of the iframe keep growing indefinitely? It only happens on Iphone. The div below as a result continues scrolling down indefinitely

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@lemiericette1/video/6892399695595965697" data-video-id="6892399695595965697" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@lemiericette1" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@lemiericette1">@lemiericette1</a> <p><a title="banana" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/banana">#banana</a> <a title="chocolate" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/chocolate">#chocolate</a> <a title="dessert" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/dessert">#dessert</a> <a title="new" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/new">#new</a> <a title="idea" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/idea">#idea</a></p> <a target="_blank" title="♬ sonido original - s.o.n.i.d.o" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/sonido-original-6871655704382556930">♬ sonido original - s.o.n.i.d.o</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
    <div>
      hello
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show us your CSS, if you have any?

Comment: I created this very simple page precisely because I thought it was a problem with my css. But it doesn't work even with this page without css

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by limit it's parent element with a maximum height value, like this:

```
blockquote {
   max-height:500px;
}
```

or in html

```
<blockquote style="max:height:500px"...
```

Comment: This seems to work, however being a fixed value, if there is a video with a longer description, the iframe will be cut

Comment: I set a maximum height of 800px because if I set a size of 1000px to make it work even with videos with longer descriptions, the problem recurs